# Angular: Make a copy of actual data not working

Tags: angularjs, copy

On API Success response. I'm trying to make a copy of data but on $scope change it gets affected too. I'm Working with Angular Component structure project.

Example

```
var actualData = $scope.data;
var workingData = $scope.data;
```

Now later on in project if workingData changes, it also changes actualData.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use angular.copy(source, [destination]) to make a deep copy of the original object.

```
angular.copy(actualData,workingData)
```

Comment: angular.copy worked but as below workingData = angular.copy(actualData);